# Partial convert sql results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that returns some data that looks like `09/25/2016, 10/16/2016, 10/23/2016`, I'd like to convert it to look something like `Sept 25, 2016, Oct 16,2016, Oct 23,2016`. I know I can convert the string to date and then back to string that looks like I want with a query like `Convert(nvarchar(20),CONVERT(datetime, '09/25/2016', 102), 107)` but have no idea how I can convert a portion of the data and build that or maybe something that can convert the whole thing.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using (presumably SQL Server).  Also, what is a "cell"?  That is not a SQL term.

Comment: Are you taking about excel?

Comment: No, I do mean sql. I'm not sure what a single column value on a single row is called.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm clear, you have a column that stores multiple dates separated by commas?

Comment: That is exactly what I have, the column has comma separated dates.

Comment: Ugh...delimited data like this violates 1NF and horrible to work with. Now consider just how truly absurd your "delimited" data is going to when you bastardize it by shoving a bunch of extra commas in there. Don't do this to yourself. Parse this disaster into a properly normalized table, use the date datatype. If you actually do this you won't have to ask us how to wrestle this nightmare around all the time. It will be super simple to work with.

Comment: I understand that it is horrible in both how it looks and works but its existing stuff that cant be changed without unraveling a bunch of other things. If it cant be done without another big mess of a query to fix it then that's that.

Comment: If you suddenly change this to be formatted date information with commas how are you going to parse this out? suddenly the existing commas are conflicting with the data. If this was mine to work with I would put the effort into fixing this instead of just continuing the pain. I totally understand how it often far beyond the current piece of work but sometimes actually making something right is required. If you continue down this path you can't even use a splitter to parse this disastrous design because your delimiter is ambiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really need to fix your table schema, anyway to get what you are after you would need to do something like..... (This would have been a much simpler query only if you would followed the simple rules of data normilization).

**Sample Data**

```
declare @T Table (ID INT , DateValues VARCHAR(1000)) 
INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(1 , '09/25/2016, 10/16/2016, 10/23/2016'),
(2 , '10/25/2016, 11/16/2016, 12/24/2016');
```

**Query**

```
WITH X AS (
SELECT  ID
        , CONVERT( VARCHAR(12) 
                 , CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'))) AS DATETIME) 
                 , 107) Dates
FROM   
    (SELECT  ID
            ,Cast ('<X>' + Replace(DateValues, ',', '</X><X>') + '</X>' AS XML) AS Data
    FROM    @T
    ) AS t CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/X') AS Split(a) 
)
SELECT ID
     ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' +  Dates
             FROM X b 
             WHERE a.id = b.id 
             FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,'') AS DateValues
FROM X a
GROUP BY ID
```

**Output**

```
╔════╦══════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ ID ║                DateValues                ║
╠════╬══════════════════════════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ Sep 25, 2016, Oct 16, 2016, Oct 23, 2016 ║
║  2 ║ Oct 25, 2016, Nov 16, 2016, Dec 24, 2016 ║
╚════╩══════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below:

`SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(),'MMM dd, yyyy')`

replace GETDATE() with any date you want